# What does the function fn:data() do in exist-db?

Tags: database, exist-db

I would like to know what the `fn:data()` function does in exist-db. I can't find the answer anywhere on the web.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the answer to my own question. If anyone else is wondering about this, you can find more here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/xquery/data-accessor-functions-data-xquery?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 3):

It seems you have found one documentation of the `data` function, however, that is part of the MS SQL Server XQuery support.

In general, the W3C XQuery/XPath/XSLT functions are specified in https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/, so the `data` function in https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-data.

Or use the eXist-db documentation if you want an eXist-db specific documentation, searchable at http://www.exist-db.org/exist/apps/fundocs/index.html: for the `data` function http://www.exist-db.org/exist/apps/fundocs/view.html?uri=http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions&location=java:org.exist.xquery.functions.fn.FnModule&details=true#data.1

For the `data` function it might not matter but in general the "XQuery" support in non-XML databases like MS SQL is often not complete and/or not based on the current/latest spec so I would start with the W3C specification and then look at vendor specific documentation for the XQuery implementation in use instead of using third party documentation.